# Better way of updating several states using react hook inside if statement?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a simple app that user can increment or decrement number of adult, child and baby.

I want to manage these state inside one state as a form of object like this below.

```
  const [numberState, setNumberState] = useState({
    adultCount: 0,
    childCount: 0,
    babyCount: 0
  });
```

And below code is the part where user can increase or decrease number of adult, child and baby.

```
            <div className="tit">Number</div>
                <dl>
                    <dt><span>Adult</span></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <div className="number_count">
                                <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("adult", "minus")}>minus</button>
                                <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={adultCount} /></span>
                                <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("adult", "plus")}>plus</button>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    <dt><span>Child</span></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <div className="number_count">
                                <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("child", "minus")}>minus</button>
                                <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={childCount} /></span>
                                <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("child", "plus")}>plus</button>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    <dt><span>Baby</span></dt>
                        <dd>
                            <div className="number_count">
                                <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("baby", "minus")}>minus</button>
                                <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={babyCount} /></span>
                                <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("baby", "plus")}>plus</button>
                            </div>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
                </div>
```

As you can see when user clicks the button, it passes two arguments to **handleNumberState** callback function.

Then function looks like this below.

```
const handleNumberState = useCallback((gen, state) => {
  if (gen === "adult" && state === "minus" && numberState.adultCount > 0) {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount - 1,
        childCount: prevState.childCount,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount
      }
    }) 
  }
  if (gen === "adult" && state === "plus") {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount + 1,
        childCount: prevState.childCount,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount
      }
    }) 
  }
  if (gen === "child" && state === "minus" && numberState.childCount > 0) {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount,
        childCount: prevState.childCount - 1,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount
      }
    }) 
  }
  if (gen === "child" && state === "plus") {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount,
        childCount: prevState.childCount + 1,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount
      }
    }) 
  }
  if (gen === "baby" && state === "minus" && numberState.babyCount > 0) {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount,
        childCount: prevState.childCount,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount - 1
      }
    }) 
  }
  if (gen === "baby" && state === "plus") {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return {
        adultCount: prevState.adultCount,
        childCount: prevState.childCount,
        babyCount: prevState.babyCount + 1
      }
    }) 
  }
})
```

Depends on what arguments get passed to the function, state is changed inside if statement.

But the code seems messy.

Is there a better way I can make this work using less if statement?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: @ksav Yeah I forgot to mention that I want to use states only inside of a component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update handler to take a field and value instead.

```
const handleNumberState = (field, value) => {
  setNumberState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [field]: Math.max(0, prevState[field] + value),
  }))
}
```

Pass the field name and value to add to the handler.

```
<div className="tit">Number</div>
<dl>
  <dt>
    <span>Adult</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <div className="number_count">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_minus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("adultCount", -1)}
      >
        minus
      </button>
      <span className="input-num">
        <input type="number" value={adultCount} />
      </span>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_plus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("adultCount", 1)}
      >
        plus
      </button>
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dt>
    <span>Child</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <div className="number_count">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_minus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("childCount", -1)}
      >
        minus
      </button>
      <span className="input-num">
        <input type="number" value={childCount} />
      </span>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_plus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("childCount", 1)}
      >
        plus
      </button>
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dt>
    <span>Baby</span>
  </dt>
  <dd>
    <div className="number_count">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_minus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("babyCount", -1)}
      >
        minus
      </button>
      <span className="input-num">
        <input type="number" value={babyCount} />
      </span>
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn_plus"
        onClick={() => handleNumberState("babyCount", 1)}
      >
        plus
      </button>
    </div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

[image: Edit better-way-of-updating-several-states-using-react-hook-inside-if-statement]

A minor optimization would be to create a curried handler that consumes a value and returns a callback function consuming the click event

```
const handleNumberState = value => e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name } = e.target;
  setNumberState((prevState) => ({
    ...prevState,
    [name]: Math.max(0, prevState[name] + value)
  }));
};
```

Give each button a `name` attribute which is passed with the click event, ex

```
<button
  name="adultCount"
  type="button"
  className="btn_minus"
  onClick={handleNumberState(-1)}
>
  minus
</button>
<span className="input-num">
  <input type="number" value={adultCount} />
</span>
<button
name="adultCount"
  type="button"
  className="btn_plus"
  onClick={handleNumberState(1)}
>
  plus
</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You may want to `useReducer`

```
const initialState = { adultCount: 0, childCount: 0, babyCount: 0 };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "increment":
      return { ...state, [action.payload]: state[action.payload] + 1 };
    case "decrement":
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.payload]: Math.max(state[action.payload] - 1, 0),
      };
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}

...

const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

...

onClick={() => dispatch({type: "increment", payload:"adultCount"})}
```

Comment: This is a cleaner and more scalable approach especially when something like redux

Comment: @malikbagwala You do not have to be using redux to make use of `useReducer`.

Comment: @ksav I am well aware of that. I just meant this makes things consistent when you are also using something like redux

Answer (score 2):

Change your handler to this:

```
const handleNumberState = useCallback((gen, state) => {
    setNumberState(prevState => {
      return { ...prevState, [gen]: prevState[gen] + state }
    }) 
  })
```

and update your `handleNumberState` arguments like below, passing the name and the value that needs to be added i.e 1(for plus) & (-1)minus. This will reduce your function handleNumberState and help get rid of lengthy code.

```
<div className="tit">Number
      <dl>
        <dt><span>Adult</span></dt>
            <dd>
                <div className="number_count">
                    <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("adultCount", -1)}>minus</button>
                    <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={adultCount} /></span>
                    <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("adultCount", +1)}>plus</button>
                </div>
            </dd>
        <dt><span>Child</span></dt>
            <dd>
                <div className="number_count">
                    <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("childCount", -1)}>minus</button>
                    <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={childCount} /></span>
                    <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("childCount", +1)}>plus</button>
                </div>
            </dd>
        <dt><span>Baby</span></dt>
            <dd>
                <div className="number_count">
                    <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("babyCount", -1)}>minus</button>
                    <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={babyCount} /></span>
                    <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => handleNumberState("babyCount", +1)}>plus</button>
                </div>
            </dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion (and the one given by the React developers in their [FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-one-or-many-state-variables)) would be to separate out those state variables into three separate ones, so that they can be updated independently of one another.

Once those are separated, you can actually remove that whole `handleNumberState()` function completely, and replace the onClick with callbacks that call your set methods.

```js
const [adultCount, setAdultCount] = useState(0);
const [childCount, setChildCount] = useState(0);
const [babyCount, setBabyCount] = useState(0);

...

<div className="tit">Number</div>
   <dl>
      <dt><span>Adult</span></dt>
         <dd>
            <div className="number_count">
               <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => if (adultCount > 0) { setAdultCount(adultCount - 1) }}>minus</button>
               <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={adultCount} /></span>
               <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => setAdultCount(adultCount + 1)}>plus</button>
            </div>
         </dd>
      <dt><span>Child</span></dt>
         <dd>
            <div className="number_count">
               <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => if (childCount > 0) { setChildCount(childCount - 1) }}>minus</button>
               <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={childCount} /></span>
               <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => setChildCount(childCount + 1)}>plus</button>
            </div>
         </dd>
      <dt><span>Baby</span></dt>
         <dd>
            <div className="number_count">
               <button type="button" className="btn_minus" onClick={() => if (babyCount > 0) { setBabyCount(babyCount - 1) }}>minus</button>
               <span className="input-num"><input type="number" value={babyCount} /></span>
               <button type="button" className="btn_plus" onClick={() => setBabyCount(babyCount + 1)}>plus</button>
            </div>
         </dd>
      </dl>
  </div>
```